# How to delare required type of Object literal in the Typescript

Tags: typescript

Lets consider simple code

```
interface Foo{
  bar:string;
  idx:number;
}


const test1:Foo={bar:'name'}; // this is very good - missing non optional field
const test2={bar:'name'} as Foo; // this is bad

[1,2,3].map(i=>(
  {
      idx:i //this is obviously invalid as name is missing, compiler should catch it
  } as Foo)
);

[1,2,3].map(i=>{
  const foo:Foo={ //This is very good but I would like to ommit assignment. 
      idx:i
  };
  return foo;
})
```

In case of short lambdas I would like to omit assignment of the variable and yet let compiler to know what type object literal should be so error will be shown.

How can I delcare object literal type in sucha way without errorprone casing via `as Foo`?

Since I was accused of beeing inaccurate, using bad examples and invalid use of map, arrays (which is simply irrelevant in this example bad code) here is something which I hope is more verbose

```
    interface Foo {
        bar:string;
        idx:number;
    }
      const arr:any[]=[]; // no I cannot declare it as Foo[], this would be too obvious. 
    
//this is not a foo! force compiler to check if it matches foo
      [1,2,3].forEach(i=>arr.push({idx:i} as Foo));; 



//this works, but how to do it without assignment
      [1,2,3].forEach(i=>{
        const foo:Foo={idx:i};// compiler correctly complains
        arr.push(foo);
   }
```

[Here is a playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=28&ssc=3&pln=8&pc=1#code/PTAEEFQYwGwQwM4NAS2XUCAOBTKK4ZQAXAT11AHsAzUAKTgDc4BlKAJxS2KoCMArPDwDuACxRRRAWABQIVOhjC4pZBxxxiOACahGBUBiiUAdgmLsArlGKV2AOlAAVUTgQ5o8JG9ny4Nw1AYSh4YFABrD0oBIQQAGkMTXVEmDzgTVBNXTmJ0qA9zKxtLdhxfMAQUAFsUeHYSSiD0gHNLOGa3TGtRQ2QGZmAAYQBiYBZhFGpie1ly0AAJHFKAcnQMnAAPOCqsGA9YRAQALlmZFBMtdmp-DwAxSkoAb1lQUF44diPC8%20aAbhfUNoNkcTJYqrwlv8ZABfU6yYxmHhacwARiO90oAF5Hu9PssTNscMtob9QPJiOJkGg9EtSKBmg9dABaUA1JA-UAmUxUbgoUyEUDUFA4GDaeGmcwkNzEABM2NxR3xhOJvVAGNJ5MpCjecDFMlkAG0UXEZXEAMwAXXsVTgWAAFChMQA%20O0A54yV6ewHAlBk4AU6nU6L6SiWBAwOnnZhhXSITmE7VsyomZoA6GqjEASlkmahhuNpst1ttDud7teCMl1Ae6Ie2L9LkDyEYtPpjIBXpQQKOKDTUNepWIJQy1coUOhmaAA)

I would gladly see a syntax like `{name:bar}:Foo` to denote that literal must mach `Foo` instead of force casting is with `as`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have found the answer that satisfies me. Specify generic return type of `map`,  but that applies to generics only. I would still want something more like `{name:bar}:Foo`

```
[1,2,3].map<Foo>(i=>(
  {
      idx:i //now this works
  })
);
```

Comment: I was just about to point that out to you, since you'd provided an actual example.

Comment: What do you mean "but that applies to generics only"? What specific (again) example do you have where it would come up without generics?

Comment: Simple. Consider `map` not having generic type. I have included workaround on how to do it via additional assignment (the 'good' map variant). My question is how to avoid that in general case.

Comment: No, it's not simple. A non-generic `map` would have **specific types**. So please, again, a specific example?

Comment: Side note: Please, please stop showing incorrect use of `map`.

Comment: Specially for you a foreach example ;) https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=7&ssc=112&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4FgBQyRyARnFAFwDOYUoA5gNwHHLAAmAHhSAK4C2JaM3wBfFsgToQNZOUpwQATwDaAXQC86kRJUBGADQAmAwGY1AOhjooAUUQALABTANAPnkWADryrPsHNzAonJUaJgAlBGMjMgA9HFgDsBhKcgg6GByyNboAIQ5NkiS6PxewAA20MhgWAgOEAgA1mwwbFn8cGD1EGG5QA

Comment: You would use a proper type on the array: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4FgBQyRyARnFAFwDOYUoA5gNwHHLAAmAHhSAK4C2JaM3wBfFsgToQNZOUoZ0AbQC6yALzJVIiUoCMAGgBMBgMwqAdDHRQAoogAWACmDqAfPIsAHXlWfYObmBRAEoQxmQAekiwB2AqNgSQdDA5ZGt0AEJ0myRJdH4vYAAbaGQwLAQHCAQAazYYNlT+ODAqiASMoA (Also: That code is `map` done the hard way. It should just use `map`, since you **are** using the result.)

Comment: I want to put any type into that array for whatever reasons.